# I need help setting up Apache2 with Mono to accept web pages from Visual Studio

Tags: apache2, mono

Does anyone know how to add the correct file path and URL path when installing a web page from Visual Studio to Ubuntu Server? I have mod_mono configured and everything that I need to server web pages directly to my server from a remote host. I have not edited any files to allow anything, nor have I tried, but the mono packages were installed and are enabled. I do not want to mess anything up. If anyone knows how to configure Apache2 with mono to enable a remote host to server web pages and the proper file configuration, it would be much appreciated. I have spent days on this already and still con not get the outcome I desire.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get install mono-apache-server libapache2-mod-mono
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName [SITE].[DOMAIN].com
    MonoAutoApplication disabled
    AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd
    MonoSetEnv MONO_IOMAP=all
    MonoApplications "/:/var/www/site"
    MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/site>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            SetHandler mono
            DirectoryIndex index.aspx index.html
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> sudo a2ensite site
>
> sudo service apache2 reload

:)